Glue Catalog Metadata Management with Enforced Tagging in Databricks
As part of the data governance team, we're trying to enforce table-level tagging when users create tables in a Databricks environment where metadata is managed by AWS Glue Catalog (non-Unity Catalog). Is there a way to require tagging at table creation, or to set up a process that enforces tagging in such an environment? Any guidance on best practices or tools to implement this would be appreciated
